# Looping iOS14 VideoPlayer

Tags: swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and I'm not massively sure how to loop a video using VideoPlayer on iOS 14 and I've found little documentation around it. Most of the solutions I have found out there are super complex and confusing in many ways. I'd be ever so grateful if anyone can help.

VideoPlayerHelper.swift File

```
import Foundation
import AVKit
//AutoPlay Video
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?

func playVideo(fileName: String, fileFormat: String) -> AVPlayer {
    if Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileFormat) != nil {
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileFormat)!)
//        videoPlayer?.play()
        
    }
    return videoPlayer!
}
```

VideoPlayerView.swift File

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var videoSelected: String
    var videoTitle: String
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: playVideo(fileName: videoSelected, fileFormat: "mp4"))
} }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you add a Notification observer onAppear and everytime the player ends, you set the time to 0 and start playing again.

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YourURL", withExtension: "mp4")!)
   var body: some View {
       VideoPlayer(player: player)
               .frame(width: 400, height: 300, alignment: .center)
               .onAppear {
                   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                       player.seek(to: .zero)
                       player.play()
                   }
               }
     
   }
}
```

Do tick the answer right if this helps

Comment: Code inside observer gives this warning. Main actor-isolated property 'player' can not be referenced from a Sendable closure; this is an error in Swift 6

Answer (score 5):

I travelled the Internet far and wide in search of the rumored SwiftUI looping video. I thought I'd share the culmination of all my Stack Overflowing (including this post) and searchengining.

*Note that `playerLooper` needs to be retained or the video won't loop.*

```
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct LoopingVideoPlayer: View {
    private var player: AVQueuePlayer
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .onAppear { player.play() }
            .onDisappear{ player.pause() }
    }
    
    init(videoURL: URL) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        
        player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: item)
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
    }
}

#Preview {
    LoopingVideoPlayer(videoURL: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods/2022/dc1310af-8cb9-4218-8d40-26bbe6a1d307/anim/hero/large_2x.mp4")!)
        .disabled(true) // Hides iOS video controls
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

Comment: humor is always a nice touch

Answer (score 0):

Use AVQueuePlayer with an AVPlayerLooper as described in this blog post:
https://schwiftyui.com/swiftui/playing-videos-on-a-loop-in-swiftui

As of SwiftUI 4, it's actually a cleaner solution than the built-in VideoPlayer because it flows with the layout and allows standard view manipulations like opacity.